# Using PWM to adjust TIM ARR for drive Stepper Motor on STM32F103C8T6

Tags: stm32

My question is using stm32 pwm to drive stepper motor, i want to adjust the TIM2->ARR=arr1 parameter to adjust the stepper speed, but if i set this parameter it doen't work in interrupt.

```
void HAL_TIM_PWM_PulseFinishedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{

    if (htim->Instance == TIM2)
    {
        //判断电机1步数中断
        if (motor1_pwm_count < Global_RunStep) //Motor1_Step是全局变量
        {
            if(accelerate_len > 0)
            {

                    int result = PowerTLine[accelerate_len];  //PowerTLine数组为Float浮点型，用int 整形一下传入arr不会卡死
//                  TIM2->ARR=result;
//                  TIM2->CCR1=result / 2;
                    accelerate_len--;
                    printf("\n  acc is :  %d \r\n",result);

            }



            motor1_pwm_count++; // 步进电机行走步数
        }
        else
        {
            HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop_IT(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

            motor1_pwm_count = 0;
            accelerate_len = 200;
//          end_accelerate_len = 0;
            Global_RunStep= 0 ;

            //步进电机ENV 使能设置 关闭
            //          MOTOR_ENV_LOW;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please detail your problem. What do you mean by "it does not work" ? You don't get interrupt anymore ? And you get one when you don't set ARR register ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.